# Trying to publish an R notebook and keep getting the same error (Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror

Tags: r, rstudio

I use OSX Yosemite with XQuartz as was suggested in other questions, and I've been attempting to publish a notebook but get the same error every time. This is what the .R file looks like:

```
#' ---
#' title: "MLB Payroll Analysis"
#' author: "Steven Quartz Universe"
#' date: "21 March 2015"
#' output: pdf_document
#' ---

#loading the payroll data from the Python document
payroll <- read.table("~/Documents/payroll.txt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")

View(payroll)

summary(payroll)

bank <- payroll$PayrollMillions
wins <- payroll$X2014Wins

#loading the payroll data from the Python document
payroll <- read.table("~/Documents/payroll.txt", header=TRUE, quote="\"")

summary(payroll)

bank <- payroll$PayrollMillions
wins <- payroll$X2014Wins

#displaying the mean and sd of payroll and wins (out of 162, of course)
mean(bank)
sd(bank)
mean(wins)
sd(wins)

#setting a linear regression
reg <- lm(wins ~ bank)
summary(reg)
#the regression is valid to significance < .10 (p-value .05072),
#but the R-squared is only .1296, a weak correlation

#a means of comparing the histogram to a normal distribution
histNorm <- function(x, densCol = "darkblue"){
  m <- mean(x)
  std <- sqrt(var(x))
  h <- max(hist(x,plot=FALSE)$density)
  d <- dnorm(x, mean=m, sd=std)
  maxY <- max(h,d)
  hist(x, prob=TRUE,
       xlab="x", ylim=c(0, maxY),
       main="(Probability) Histogram with Normal Density")
  curve(dnorm(x, mean=m, sd=std),
        col=densCol, lwd=2, add=TRUE)
}

#showing the histogram with normal distribution line
histNorm(reg$residuals, "purple")

#QQplots and Shapiro-Wilk test
qqnorm(reg$residuals)
qqline(reg$residuals)
shapiro.test(reg$residuals)
#p-value is .383; this can be considered a normal distribution

plot(reg$fitted.values,reg$residuals)
abline(h = 0)
#variances are wide, but in a channel

install.packages("lmtest")
library(lmtest)
bptest(reg)
#p-value of .849 given; we can assume variances are constant throughout the     distribution

hats <- hatvalues(reg)

hatmu <- mean(hats)
hats[hats > 2 * hatmu]
#we get teams 14 and 19 with high leverage; the Dodgers and Yankees with their     astronomical payrolls

treg <- rstudent(reg)
n <- length(treg)
p <- reg$coefficients
df <- n - p - 1
alpha <- 0.05

#no bonferroni correction for outliers
crit <- qt(1 - alpha/2,df)
treg[abs(treg) > crit]
#no outliers are found

#with bonferroni correction
crit <- qt(1 - (alpha/2)/n,df)
treg[abs(treg) > crit]
#no outliers are found

#comparison of outlier tests
pvals <- pt(-abs(treg),df)*2
padjb <- p.adjust(pvals, method = "bonferroni")
padjf <- p.adjust(pvals, method = "fdr")
cbind(pvals,padjb,padjf)
```

When I hit Compile Notebook, this is the output:

```
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1


processing file: payroll.spin.Rmd

Quitting from lines 9-90 (payroll.spin.Rmd) 
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> install.packages ->     contrib.url
```

I've looked through other questions on how to rectify this, but to no avail. I've done the command line fixes, again to no avail. Could someone point me as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks kindly.

Comment: Could you pls add some more info... What does your `contrib.url` line look like (and if it uses variables as parameters, what is the content of those)? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: OP here...not sure what a contrib.url line is and where I'd place it. I removed View from the non-interactive script.

Comment: Hmm do you have an `install.packages` command somewhere?

Comment: Just added the full .R file

Comment: I think specifying a repos to your `install.packages` function call should do it. (See at the end of this page: http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100165280/error-in-installing-package)

Comment: Dominic, you're the best! Thank you so much! How can I possibly repay you?

Comment: Haha a cheque might do. Or just upvote my comments ;)

Comment: Can do...if there were arrows instead of just comments. Stack confuses me so much! :O

Comment: Usually when you hover left of the comment, you would see an up arrow and a little flag. If you don't it's probly b/c you don't have enough rep points yet. Don't worry about it!

Comment: @DominicComtois, post as answer pls, possibly giving a less link-dependent answer?

Comment: @BenBolker Ok will do

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to have `install.packages()` in a script you plan to run multiple times. You should only install a package once. You should, however, leave the call to load the package in the script (ie `library()`)

Comment: or use `if (!require(pkg)) { install.packages(pkg); library(pkg) }` (you might need `character.only=TRUE` if you specify the pkg as a string).  I would also consider it slightly impolite to have a script install a package without explicitly asking me if I want to do it ...

Answer (score 18):

The line

```
install.packages("lmtest")
```

is the problem here. As is hinted by the error message

```
Error in contrib.url(repos, "source") : 
  trying to use CRAN without setting a mirror
```

it is expected that you provide a link to a repo for the package. So changing it to (for instance):

```
install.packages("lmtest", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

should do the trick. But as MrFlick and Ben Bolkers pointed out in their comments, it should probably be done when the package is not already installed.

Comment: (or some more geographically appropriate mirror, if you don't live in or near the US)

Answer (score 12):

I had this same issue with a Knit HTML publish, i modified the very beginning of the file like so:

````
---
title: "dialectic"
author: "micah smith"
date: "3/4/2017"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
chooseCRANmirror(graphics=FALSE, ind=1)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
````

the `chooseCRANmirror(graphics=FALSE, ind=1)` was the line that fixed it

Answer (score 5):

```
chooseCRANmirror(graphics=FALSE, ind=1)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Write this at the start of your chunk if you have already installed the package.

Answer (score 1):

If you have already run your install.packages("___") script, then you can try to set that codechunk to eval = FALSE when you try to knit your markdown file?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing multiple packages via a `pkgs` variable just do this. It worked for me. I couldn't knitr to pdf until I fixed it.

```
pkgs <- c("moments", "ggplot2", "dplyr", "tidyr", "tidyverse")
install.packages(pkgs, repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```